# Using C++ template parameter as argument to another template?

Tags: c++, templates, syntax-error

I'm trying to get the code below to compile:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
static void addMapping(const K& id, const V& index, std::map<K, V>& mapset) 
{
    std::pair< std::map<K, V>::iterator, bool > ret;
    // ...
}
```

but I get the following error message:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _T1, class _T2> struct std::pair’
     std::pair< std::map<K, V>::iterator, bool > ret;
```

I recall that there's something special you need to write when you want to use a template parameter as an argument to another template, but I don't remember what that was...

Comment: I think you need `typename` before you template parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line:

```
std::pair< std::map<K, V>::iterator, bool > ret;
```

into:

```
std::pair< typename std::map<K, V>::iterator, bool > ret;
```

As `std::map<K, V>::iterator` depends on the template arguments you need to tell the compiler it's a type.